# How can I open another JFrame through a JComboBox selection?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm a beginner to Java and I'm trying to make a simple virtual library where the user can browse for books (the books will be contained in a `JFrame`) through a `JComboBox` selection. When the user selects a book from the list and press "OK", it will take them to another specific frame depending on their selection.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What IDE are you using? also if its eclipse are you using window builder?

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE 12.2

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your books are separate classes you can just call them respectively. Assuming that these separates classes are inside a JFrame

```
class book1 extends JFrame{
  //book contents
}

class book2 extends JFrame{
  //book contents
}

class book3 extends JFrame{
  //book contents
}

public class Main { //this class can also be in a GUI
   public static void main(String args[]){
     String booklist[] = { "Book1", "Book2", "Book3"};

     JComboBox myBooks = new JComboBox(booklist);
     
     //Add an event listener based on your preference. Code below is just for example im not sure if its the right syntax but you get the point.
     mybook.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          String value = (String) myBooks.getSelectedItem(); // get the selected item in the combobox
        switch(value){
        case "Book1":
            book1 b1 = new book1(); // call the class
            b1.setVisible(true);    // set the jframe to visible 
            break;
        case "Book2":
            book2 b2 = new book2();
            b2.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case "Book3":
            book3 b3 = new book3();
            b3.setVisible(true);
            break;
        }          
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: It shows an error for the switch case which is 
'incompatible types: JComboBox cannot be converted to int'

Comment: (1-) 1) Class names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions. Learn by example from the class names in the API. 2) an application should only have a single JFrame. Child windows should be a JDialog.

Comment: @camickr sorry. I know that class names should start at small letters i didnt notice that. 2. I was answering his "question" which he says books are inside the jframe.

Comment: @Schwiro I forgot. You need to get the selected item. `String value = (String) myBooks.getSelectedItem();` before using them in the switch case

Comment: @GeromeTahud, Part of answering a question to is suggest a better approach when one is available.

Comment: @GeromeTahud Appreciate your help, thanks!